# Sorting keep shifting rows when there's 11+ rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

**See code in jsfiddle links provided below**

There's a bunch of ways to sort a table using javascript (+jquery) out there. I started using James Padolsey's jquery sort plugin. I had to modified his demo code since it did not check for equality (it was only checking greater and less than).

Everything works fine until there's 11+ rows in the table and 3 of the row are the same. The 3 rows kept shifting after each sort. [You can try it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/uvHbH/2/); keep clicking on "Fruit" and notice the "apple" rows are shifting. If you remove one of the table row, the shifting stop and the sort is correct.

I started to see if I can write my own sort and use the js array sort and I ran into the same problem. [You can play with it here](http://jsfiddle.net/hQ7NK/3/). Notice that I am sorting by first column only and in ascending every time when you click a table header. **Ascending every time and it is still shifting the "apple" rows.**

It appears that this is a Javascript array sort issue (since James' plugin is using it too)? Any one have any idea on this or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended it up sorting the other columns if the current data I'm sorting is equal. I also decided to mod James' demo code to support this (not his plugin code). http://jsfiddle.net/C8nQ2/1/

The below recursive function support more than 2 columns table. It will go through the column to sort, if it equals, it continue to the next column, etc.

```
function calc(a, b, first) {
    var valueA = $(a).text(),
        valueB = $(b).text();

    if(valueA == valueB) {
        // 1st time calling & sort is not on 1st column so sort the first by column
        if(first && (index != 0)) {
            return calc(a.parent().children().eq(0), b.parent().children().eq(0));
        }

        // no more columns to sort, both rows are exactly the same
        if(a.index() == th.length - 1) { 
            return 0; 
        }

        // sort by the next column
        return calc(a.next(), b.next());
    } else {
        return (isNaN(valueA) || isNaN(valueB) ? valueA > valueB : +valueA > +valueB) ? inverse ? -1 : 1 : inverse ? 1 : -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to sort on more than one column, then. JavaScript isn't doing anything you haven't told it to do.

```
$('th').click(function(){
    var header = $(this);
    // only sorting the by the 1st column (for now) and in ascending only
    header.closest('table').find('tbody tr').sort(function(a, b) {
        var compA = $(a).find('td:first-child').text().toUpperCase();
        var compB = $(b).find('td:first-child').text().toUpperCase();
        var compC = +$(a).find('td:first-child').next().text();
        var compD = +$(b).find('td:first-child').next().text();

        if(compA < compB) { 
            return -1;
        }
        else if(compA > compB) {
            return 1;
        }
        else if(compC < compD) { 
            return -1;
        }
        else if(compC > compD) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }).appendTo(header.closest('table')); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/hQ7NK/4/

Comment: That was what I was going to do as a fix. I just don't understand why js is sorting "Apple" again even after it already been sorted asc?

Comment: @user1118188  Because the JavaScript `sort` function may not look at the array elements in the same order you do.

Comment: If that is the case, then why does 10 or less rows works fine and anything more than 11 rows doesn't? I truly think this is a js sort bug.

Comment: Then you're welcome to submit it as one. Just don't expect them to change anything, since technically your result is exactly what your code asked for.

Comment: I'm too lazy to go through the process of submitting a bug to who ever they are. But by returning 0 in the sort, I expect the position to be the same each time the sort is perform. In this case, it does for 10 or less but not 11 or more rows which boggles my mind. @mblase75, thanks for your help.

Comment: @user1118188 Don't forget to accept your favorite answer on all your questions.

Answer (score 0):

From jQuery 1.7's source code:

```
// For internal use only.
// Behaves like an Array's method, not like a jQuery method.
sort: [].sort,
```

Instead, try something like [James Padolsey's solution](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/):

```
/**
 * jQuery.fn.sortElements
 * --------------
 * http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/
 * @param Function comparator:
 *   Exactly the same behaviour as [1,2,3].sort(comparator)
 *   
 * @param Function getSortable
 *   A function that should return the element that is
 *   to be sorted. The comparator will run on the
 *   current collection, but you may want the actual
 *   resulting sort to occur on a parent or another
 *   associated element.
 *   
 *   E.g. $('td').sortElements(comparator, function(){
 *      return this.parentNode; 
 *   })
 *   
 *   The <td>'s parent (<tr>) will be sorted instead
 *   of the <td> itself.
 */
jQuery.fn.sortElements = (function(){

    var sort = [].sort;

    return function(comparator, getSortable) {

        getSortable = getSortable || function(){return this;};

        var placements = this.map(function(){

            var sortElement = getSortable.call(this),
                parentNode = sortElement.parentNode,

                // Since the element itself will change position, we have
                // to have some way of storing its original position in
                // the DOM. The easiest way is to have a 'flag' node:
                nextSibling = parentNode.insertBefore(
                    document.createTextNode(''),
                    sortElement.nextSibling
                );

            return function() {

                if (parentNode === this) {
                    throw new Error(
                        "You can't sort elements if any one is a descendant of another."
                    );
                }

                // Insert before flag:
                parentNode.insertBefore(this, nextSibling);
                // Remove flag:
                parentNode.removeChild(nextSibling);

            };

        });

        return sort.call(this, comparator).each(function(i){
            placements[i].call(getSortable.call(this));
        });

    };

})();
```

Comment: Hmm, I did say that I'm using his plugin and ran into the same problem. But if you read his code, it is using [].sort.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that; sorry if I wasn't very clear; I don't think [].sort() is sufficient here and I think you should try a more sophisticated plugin.